# how do I insert php code into a table style?

Tags: php

I'm a super newbie at PHP, I'm writing (or trying to write) some code. I have been trying to insert a php code into a table data cell but obviously I'm making some syntax mistake. Could you tell me what it is?

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row["translator"]; ?>
</td>
<?php echo "<td style=\"background-image:url(./assets/images/series/.$row['cover'].); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:250px 180px; width: 250px; height: 180px;\">"
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

$row must be known to PHP before. so you need to do this to work:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost"; //your db host
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT name, translator, cover FROM translators";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row["name"];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row["translator"];
echo "</td>";

echo "<td style='background-image:url("./assets/images/series/".$row['cover'].""); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:250px 180px; width: 250px; height: 180px;'>"
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah I did connect to the database and I'm getting all the info except that cover photo which should be dynamic.

Comment: I got a syntax error again.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\id\index.php on line 328

Comment: you can see the path from inspect element on your browser

Comment: @AytugSeyrek hmm. you may use this: url("./assets/images/series/".$row['cover']."")